# Detect parent domain name via script in iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am currently have i an iframe eg:
`<iframe src="www.mydomain.com/myfram.php">` and embedded to my client page with different domain name.
i want my script in `"myfram.php"` to detect parent domain(client domain) where my iframe is embedded in.
I use 
`$_SERVRE['SERVER_NAME']` but it return my domain name not client. So do you have another ways to grab client domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't even know that the page is in an `iframe`. Only JavaScript can tell you that, and even then cross-domain restrictions may interfere.

If anything will work, it'll be using AJAX to send `top.location.hostname` to the server.

Comment: I found that top.location.hostname is not return client domain name but it return the domain of an iframe (it return my domain name)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in javascript:
    parent.document.URL